# Auth0 SSO with multiple google accounts

Tags: gmail, single-sign-on, auth0

I'm setting up Auth0 with SSO enabled for multiple web sites.

I have it working perfectly for username/password connections and for google connections where the user is only logged into a single google account.

But... I have two google accounts logged in on my browser. When I go to site 1 and use the google connection, it prompts me to select a google account to log in with. That's correct.

But when I go to site 2, and attempt to stay logged in using sso data from Auth0, it still prompts me to select a google account again. Which I would not expect.

Here's my sign in code:

```
auth0.getSSOData(function (err, ssoData) {
    if (!err && ssoData.sso) {
        auth0.signin({
            connection: ssoData.lastUsedConnection.name,
            scope: 'openid email email_verified name app_metadata',
            state: 'http://localhost:21763/#/',
            authParams: {
                prompt: 'none'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I added prompt: 'none' having read this older post on Auth0 community, but to no avail. https://auth0.com/forum/t/sso-login-with-google-connection-must-select-account/4983

Has anyone else done this? I feel like it must be possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started experimenting with the possible parameters into the signin method call and stumbled across the answer...

I tried a few things, but this seems to work perfectly, moving the "prompt: 'none'" up out of the authParams to be a direct option to signin method call...

```
auth0.getSSOData(function (err, ssoData) {
    if (!err && ssoData.sso) {
        auth0.signin({
            connection: ssoData.lastUsedConnection.name,
            scope: 'openid email email_verified name app_metadata',
            state: 'http://localhost:21763/#/',
            prompt: 'none'
        });
    }
});
```